# Snapshot/Save canvas in Model/View/Controller setup

Tags: java, image, javafx, snapshot

I am having trouble setting up a snapshot/save option in my paint app, I cannot find the correct variable name for the showSaveDialog option, what exactly does that option require for it to work?

Here is the method I am using for the snapshot/save

```
     FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

            //Set extension filter
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = 
                    new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

            //Show save file dialog
            File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);

            if(file != null){
                try {
                    WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
                    canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
                    RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
                    ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaFX_DrawOnCanvas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

and here is the model class;

```
public class Paint extends Application {

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("PaintScreen.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Profile Picture Creator");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample app that uses `FileChooser`. Use the `FileChooser` to create a file in a specific location. Then use that file in the `ImageIO.write(...)` method.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BasicOpsTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Drawing Operations Test");
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        drawShapes(gc);

        Button btnSave = new Button("save");
        btnSave.setOnAction((ActionEvent actionEvent)->{

             WritableImage image = canvas.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

            // TODO: probably use a file chooser here
            //Set extension filter
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.png");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

            //Show save file dialog
            File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);

            try 
            {
                if(file != null)
                {
                    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) 
            { 
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }              
        });
        root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, btnSave);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        gc.setLineWidth(5);
        gc.strokeLine(40, 10, 10, 40);
        gc.fillOval(10, 60, 30, 30);
        gc.strokeOval(60, 60, 30, 30);
        gc.fillRoundRect(110, 60, 30, 30, 10, 10);
        gc.strokeRoundRect(160, 60, 30, 30, 10, 10);
        gc.fillArc(10, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.OPEN);
        gc.fillArc(60, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.CHORD);
        gc.fillArc(110, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.ROUND);
        gc.strokeArc(10, 160, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.OPEN);
        gc.strokeArc(60, 160, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.CHORD);
        gc.strokeArc(110, 160, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.ROUND);
        gc.fillPolygon(new double[]{10, 40, 10, 40},
                       new double[]{210, 210, 240, 240}, 4);
        gc.strokePolygon(new double[]{60, 90, 60, 90},
                         new double[]{210, 210, 240, 240}, 4);
        gc.strokePolyline(new double[]{110, 140, 110, 140},
                          new double[]{210, 210, 240, 240}, 4);
    }


}
```